# Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on a unit test suite, no apparent error details

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, azure-devops-pipelines

I am running a unit-test suite and suddenly dotnet exits with an error but an error which I cannot see what is related to ?

```
2020-09-28T14:45:44.4406132Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\ag2\_w\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
2020-09-28T14:45:45.0411575Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2020-09-28T14:45:45.0682638Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2020-09-28T14:45:45.1670771Z No Result Found to Publish 'C:\ag2\_w\_temp\bld_bc-dev-bld-01_2020-09-28_14_45_12.trx'.
2020-09-28T14:45:45.1766433Z No Result Found to Publish 'C:\ag2\_w\_temp\bld_bc-dev-bld-01_2020-09-28_14_45_27.trx'.
2020-09-28T14:45:45.1863176Z No Result Found to Publish 'C:\ag2\_w\_temp\bld_bc-dev-bld-01_2020-09-28_14_45_44.trx'.
2020-09-28T14:45:45.1889993Z Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x (3.1) SDK/Runtime along with 2.1. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 3.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. 
2020-09-28T14:45:45.1890767Z Some commonly encountered changes are: 
2020-09-28T14:45:45.1891763Z If you're using `Publish` command with -o or --Output argument, you will see that the output folder is now being created at root directory rather than Project File's directory. To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2020-09-28T14:45:45.1893725Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : 
2020-09-28T14:45:45.1924867Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2020-09-28T14:45:45.3885730Z Publishing test results to test run '564748'.
2020-09-28T14:45:45.3917393Z TestResults To Publish 21, Test run id:564748
2020-09-28T14:45:45.3960633Z Test results publishing 21, remaining: 0. Test run id: 564748
2020-09-28T14:45:45.3977089Z Publishing test results to test run '564754'.
2020-09-28T14:45:45.3978225Z TestResults To Publish 17, Test run id:564754
```

Comment: Have you ever ran a unit-test suite before? Did you meet this issue? Could you share your pipeline and detailed log? And please set variable system.debug to true to see whether you would get more details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running `dotnet publish` command. Check your pipeline whether you have similar syntax:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-o testpath'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: true
```

In addition, check the following link to see whether it helps you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting